# Problems with accented letters on website

Tags: html, wordpress, fonts

I have recently launched a website. It has 2 language versions: English and Czech.

For some reason I am having problems with Czech accented letters - they appear bold on the website. Mozilla Firefox makes bold only accented letters, Google Chrome makes bold a few words in a row.

Charset is UTF-8.
CMS: Wordpress
URL: http://www.languageatelier.eu/cs/

What could be the problem? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Roboto 300 font has only latin glyphs. The **latin extended subset** is missing.

Your fonts get's loaded here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="googlefonts_heading-css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A300%2C400%2C400italic%2C700&amp;ver=3.8.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

And should be loaded like:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Notice the get parameters `subset=latin,latin-ext`.

[image]

See: https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto