# How to render Turkish letters (Latin Extend-A?) correctly on web page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, localization, stylesheet

We're localizing our website for the Turkish language.
But somehow some accented letters are not displayed correctly.  They seem to be more bolded than the other letters.  Please see the screenshot.

[image: Turkish letters not displayed correctly]

We're using Rails.  Here's the source code of the page:

```
<span id="page"></span>
<div class="article_container">

<div class="main_col_fluid article">
    <div class="module" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<div id="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb superfluous">
<a href='/turkey/tr'>Anasayfa</a><span class='divider'> › </span><a href='/turkey/tr/world'>Dünya</a><span class='divider'> › </span><a href='/turkey/tr/world/asia-pacific'>Asya Pasifik</a>
</div>

<div class="intro">
<div class="meta_wrapper">
    <span class="meta date" itemprop="datePublished">28 Şubat 2014, Cuma</span>
</div>
<h1 itemprop="name">Temel Misyonumuz</h1>
<div class="meta_wrapper">
    <span class="meta source" itemprop="author">Abdulla al Gurg, Al Gurg Group</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="strapline" itemprop="description">
    <p>Nissan Leaf&#x27;in arka kapısındaki siyah camlar bu pilli-elektrikli arabada farklı bir şeyler olduğunun ilk ipucu. Yan tarafına yazılmış “Otonom Sürüş” kelimeleri ise durumu daha iyi anlatıyor.</p>
</div>
<ul class="actions">
<li class="share">
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php" class="addthis_button no-lightbox">
    <span class="icon"></span> Paylaş <span class="icon arrow"></span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="print superfluous">
<a href="#">
    <span class="icon"></span> Yazdır
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="media">
</div>

<div class="content" itemprop="articleBody"><p>Temel Misyonumuz, bilimsel donanım ve anlayışa sahip, &ccedil;ağdaş, demokrat, &uuml;retken, &uuml;lke ve d&uuml;nya sorunlarına duyarlı, yeniliklere a&ccedil;ık, değişen koşullara uyum g&ouml;sterebilen, geleceğe y&ouml;nelik hedefleri olan, grup i&ccedil;inde &ccedil;alışmayı bilen, liderlik ve iletişim becerilerine sahip, modern eğitim-&ouml;ğretim ve bilgi-iletişim teknolojilerini kullanabilen, farklı bilim dalları arasında ilişki kurabilen ve bilgilerini farklı alanlara uygulayabilen/yansıtabilen, k&uuml;lt&uuml;re ve sanata duyarlı, &ccedil;eşitliliği bir zenginlik olarak algılayan, teori ile uygulamayı birleştirebilen, &ouml;zg&uuml;veni ve hoşg&ouml;r&uuml;s&uuml; olan, yaşam boyu &ouml;ğrenmeyi ve kendini yenilemeyi ilke edinmiş, kendisiyle ve &ccedil;evresiyle barışık, profesyonel ve mesleğine adanmış, eleştirel, yansıtıcı ve yaratıcı d&uuml;ş&uuml;nme ile karar verme ve problem &ccedil;&ouml;zme becerilerine sahip, d&uuml;ş&uuml;ncelerini &ouml;zg&uuml;rce ifade edebilen &ouml;ğretmenler yetiştirmektir.</p>

<p>Eğitim ve &ouml;ğretimle ilgili ulusal ve uluslararası d&uuml;zeyde kuramsal ve uygulamalı bilimsel araştırma ve projelerin yanı sıra kongre, seminer, sempozyum, panel ve &ccedil;alıştaylar d&uuml;zenleyerek sonu&ccedil;larının geniş kitlelere ulaşmasını ve uygulamalar &uuml;zerinde etkili olmasını sağlamak; eğitim ve &ouml;ğretimle ilgili faaliyette bulunan resmi ve &ouml;zel, yerel, ulusal ve uluslararası kurumlarla işbirliği yaparak hem onların imkan ve tecr&uuml;belerinden yararlanmak hem de s&ouml;z konusu kurumların gelişmelerine katkıda bulunmak ise fak&uuml;ltemizin diğer &ouml;nceliklerini oluşturmaktadır.</p>
</div>
```

I have tried this, as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777211/problems-with-accented-letters-on-website)

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and also

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700&subset=latin,latin-ext" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but neither seems to have helped.

How do you suggest to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: The question lacks the code that actually takes Roboto (or Open Sans) into some use. The `link` element just defines it for use.

Comment: In the screenshot, the letters ı, ş, ç, ğ look OK. There are problems only in the headline-like text, in larger size, before the copy text. You need to show the CSS code that actually reproduces that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The mystery has been solved.  We are using a custom font we purchased from fonts.com.
Apparently this font we purchased didn't contain Latin Extend-A characters.  Any missing glyphs are rendered using a system font (probably Helvetica on the mac), hence the missing characters look bold.

The solution is to re-download the fonts including the Latin Extend-A characters.